# What spin-statistics is a magnetic monopole expected to obey?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-spin, quantum-electrodynamics, magnetic-monopoles, spin-statistics

1. What statistics  (or spin) is a [magnetic monopole](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_monopole) expected to have?
2. Does it depend on the theory used?

Comment: Is this homework?

Comment: No. But short answer will be best :)

Comment: A google search seems to bring up both types of spin, so there doesn't seem to be a well-known governing reason that is theory independent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the non-trivial topological solution of the equations of motion under consideration. The most famous example is the 't Hooft–Polyakov monopole (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%27t_Hooft%E2%80%93Polyakov_monopole) which has the following solution:
\begin{equation}
\phi = h \frac{x^a} {r} t^a
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
 A_0=0
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
A_i =  - \frac{1}{2} (1-k) \varepsilon_{ija} \frac{x^j}{r^2} t^a
\end{equation}
This system is spherically symmetric under the product $ \mathrm{SO(3)} \times \mathrm{SU(2)}$ and thus it has zero spin due to its spherically symmetric behaviour.

In short: it depend on the theory being used.